# Cannot publish item with an error " The publishing service is not running. Please contact your system administrator."

Tags: publishing-service

I have installed **Sitecore Publishing Service 4.3.0** and its counterpart module (`Sitecore Publishing Module 10.0.0.0 rev. r00568.2697.zip`) into a new clean Sitecore 10.0 XP0 by following the official manual. There were no problems while following it, all the steps seemed logical and worked as expected.

**The problem**: unless I manually run the executable (`Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe`) - no publishing happens. Once I manually run it - it loads in command prompt with default big "*Publish*" console-art and the message to press Ctrl+C to shut down. While this command prompt is open - publishing works well and items appear on the web from master as they normally should do.

However, when I close this console window, no more publishing happens and I am getting the errors:
[image: The publishing service is not running. Please contact your system administrator.]

What is interesting, the **process** `Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe` is running (as it should do) after I trigger a testing request (to `http://publishing.service/api/publishing/operations/status` getting expected `{"status":0}` response)

When I then manually run executable, I get two identical processes with one difference that manual runs under my user credentials rather than `AppPoolIdentity`, which is understandable. Also, one of processes' command line is wrapped with brackets, the other isn't, but these both are acceptable - some processes do have them, others don't. Just in case, I even tried giving app pool `Local System` account to test if that may be a case of some permissions missing, but the experiment ended that same:
[image]

As I mentioned. when I manually run `Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe` executable (the above process) - publishing works well, the item appears at Publishing Target (web database) and the task is also reflected at Publishing Dashboard.

**Logs**: look clear - no errors. At least nothing looking criminal to my eyes.

**Web.config** file within publishing service points to the correct executable. I also tried "debloating" the config as prompted at the bottom of [this blog post](http://sitecorebond.com/archive/installing-sitecore-publishing-service-220-with-one-click/), but debloating also did not fix the problem

**Service installation steps**, as I did it:

1. Created a folder and extracted everything into
2. Provided connection strings to master, web, and core databases by `.\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe configuration setconnectionstring core <value>`
3. `.\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe configuration set Sitecore:Publishing:InstanceName --value <PS_INSTANCENAME>`
4. `\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe schema upgrade --force`
5. `.\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe IIS install --hosts --force`

As for the counterpart module, I have made a config patch where referenced `PublishingService.UrlRoot` as described in the manual.

Literary, lost my head out of this issue. Am I missing something important?

Comment: Did you set the app pool to unmanaged in IIS? Since you are running the exe out of the same IIS folder,  I have to imagine your connection strings are just fine.

Comment: Sure that was my first assumption, and the automated installation by `.\Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe iis install --hosts --force` did that for me (I double checked for it).

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? Same issue here

Comment: Martin, please can you add the resolutions of this issue?

Comment: using Sitecore Publishing Service 7.0 and did all the steps above and created a patch file and there was no issues `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"> <sitecore> <settings> <setting name="PublishingService.UrlRoot" value="http://sitecore.publishing/" /> </settings> </sitecore>
</configuration>`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the similar issue with `Sitecore 10.1` and `Sitecore Publishing Service 5.0.0`.

[image]

I started the publishing service host service by using following command:

[image]

`Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host.exe`

After running this command, I am not seeing this error and able to publish the items from CMS.