# Is there a way to specify when the Publishing Service maintenance task runs?

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

Recently we've seen with the Sitecore Publishing Service 6.0 a message stating a "system maintenance task is currently running".

Is there a way to configure when this runs? Typically we see it run during normal business hours.

Initially I noticed that a second message, "publishing service is not running", even though the application was up.

[image]

After recycling the application pool for SPS that message disappeared.

[image]

Endpoints to check:

- https://[service]/api/publishing/jobs/status
- https://[service]/api/publishing/maintenance/status
- https://[service]/api/publishing/maintenance/isrunning

### Update

Looks like these scheduled tasks startup every time the application pool recycles (or hosts starts up).

```
2022-09-16 10:55:29.263 -05:00 [Information] Starting web host
2022-09-16 10:55:29.699 -05:00 [Information] Service Version   : "6.0.0"
2022-09-16 10:55:29.705 -05:00 [Information] Environment type  : "Production"
2022-09-16 10:55:29.705 -05:00 [Information] Listening on      : "http://127.0.0.1:13837"
2022-09-16 10:55:29.705 -05:00 [Information] Instance name     : "e6c2f193-2897-4088-a0d5-0d7f77e1a7e5"
2022-09-16 10:55:30.423 -05:00 [Information] Source registered : "Master" ("Master")
2022-09-16 10:55:30.424 -05:00 [Information] Target registered : "Internet" ("Internet")
2022-09-16 10:55:30.436 -05:00 [Information] Scheduled Task    : "PublishTask-4edbb2e3cd41426193173332d530f63b"
2022-09-16 10:55:30.437 -05:00 [Information] Scheduled Task    : "PublishJobCleanupTask-6ef73ea68c204f918a6e3630a8ea63d7"
2022-09-16 10:55:30.437 -05:00 [Information] Scheduled Task    : "PublishOperationAgeBasedCleanupTask-cc270b31c9474150b309820bd12858cb"
2022-09-16 10:55:30.438 -05:00 [Information] Scheduled Task    : "PublishOperationCleanupTask-7bf4e515e7594a34855ce1548fe227c5"
2022-09-16 10:55:30.441 -05:00 [Information] Starting Instance Activation monitor ("MultiInstanceActivationStrategy") on "e6c2f193-2897-4088-a0d5-0d7f77e1a7e5"
2022-09-16 10:55:30.487 -05:00 [Information] Instance Enabled  : False ("e6c2f193-2897-4088-a0d5-0d7f77e1a7e5")
2022-09-16 10:55:30.505 -05:00 [Information] Scheduler Status  : Stopped
2022-09-16 10:55:45.567 -05:00 [Information] Instance Enabled  : True ("e6c2f193-2897-4088-a0d5-0d7f77e1a7e5")
2022-09-16 10:55:45.653 -05:00 [Information] Scheduler Status  : Started
```

**Related:**

- [Cannot publish item with an error " The publishing service is not running. Please contact your system administrator."](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26466/cannot-publish-item-with-an-error-the-publishing-service-is-not-running-pleas)
- https://neilkillen.com/2020/08/24/sitecore-publishing-service-in-a-geo-distributed-environment/

Comment: This is not an answer (I don't have the "reputation" to make a comment so...) but we have the same problem. Very annoying since nothing comes out until I can restart the app pool. Appeared after the sitecore 10.2 upgrade, a rare problem but still. I've tried disabling the recycling i do of the sps app. pool now, see if that helps. But I'll create a support case as well now.

Comment: After checking the sitecore publishing logs (not the sps log) i found an error: 

8296 00:06:04 FATAL Resource files synchronization failed due to resource file reading errors. Publishing operations will be suspended
Exception: Sitecore.Publishing.Service.ResourceFiles.Exceptions.ResourceFilesServiceException